# Small Poker program in C

Tags: c, game, playing-cards

I made a small Poker program with C but I believe I could've written it better.

[Full source on bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/assyrian/c-small-poker-program/src)

```
int checkhand (struct Card_s * hand)
{
    assert (hand) ;
    //struct Card_s *suithand = sorthand(hand, true); // Unnecessary
    struct Card_s *sorted = sorthand(hand, false);

    /* check for flushes */
    {
        bool flushsuit = false;
        int suits[4] = { [0 ... 3] = 0 };
        for (int i = 0; i < MAXHAND; ++i)
        {
            switch (hand[i].nSuit)
            {
                case spades:    suits[0]++; break;
                case clubs: suits[1]++; break;
                case hearts:    suits[2]++; break;
                case diamonds:  suits[3]++; break;
            }
        }
        for ( int f = 0 ; f < 4 ; ++f )
        {
            if (suits[f] == 5) { flushsuit = true ; } /* found a flush */
        }

        if ( flushsuit )
        {
            if ( sorted[0].nType == (sorted[1].nType-1) && sorted[1].nType == (sorted[2].nType-1) && sorted[2].nType == (sorted[3].nType-1) && sorted[3].nType == (sorted[4].nType-1) )
            {
                if ( sorted[4].nType == ace ) return 10; /* found royal flush */
                else return 9; /* found straight flush */
            }
            return 6; /* it was a normal flush */
        }
    }

    /* check for 4 of a kind */
    {
        int type [MAXTYPES ] = { [0 ... 12] = 0 }, *types ;
        types = count_types( sorted, type ) ;
        for ( int f = 0 ; f < MAXTYPES ; ++f )
        {
            if ( types[f] == 4 ) { return 8 ; } /* found 4 same types in a row */
        }
    }

    /* check for full house */
    {
        bool threeKind = false, Twopair = false ;
        int type[ MAXTYPES ] = { [0 ... 12] = 0 }, *types ;

        types = count_types( sorted, type ) ;
        for ( int f = 0 ; f < MAXTYPES ; ++f )
        {
            if ( types[f] == 3 ) { threeKind = true ; } /* found three of a kind */
        }

        int pair[MAXTYPES] = { [0 ... 12] = 0 }, *pairs ;
        pairs = count_types( sorted, pair );
        for ( int f = 0 ; f < MAXTYPES ; ++f )
        {
            if ( pairs[f] == 2 ) { Twopair = true ; } /* found normal pair */
        }
        if ( threeKind && Twopair ) return 7; /* found full house */
    }

    if ( sorted[0].nType == (sorted[1].nType-1) && sorted[1].nType == (sorted[2].nType-1) && sorted[2].nType == (sorted[3].nType-1) && sorted[3].nType == (sorted[4].nType-1) )
    {
        return 5; /* found straight */
    }

    /* check for three of a kind */
    {
        int type[ MAXTYPES ] = { [0 ... 12] = 0 }, *types ;
        types = count_types( sorted, type ) ;
        for ( int f = 0 ; f < MAXTYPES ; ++f )
        {
            if ( types[f] == 3 ) { return 4 ; } /* found three of a kind */
        }
    }

    /* check for two pair */
    {
        int type[MAXTYPES] = { [0 ... 12] = 0 }, *types ;
        types = count_types( sorted, type );
        int isTwoPair = 0 ;
        for ( int f = 0 ; f < MAXTYPES ; ++f )
        {
            if (types[f] == 2) isTwoPair++;
            if (isTwoPair == 2) { return 3 ; } /* found two pair */
        }
    }

    /* check for normal pair */
    {
        int type[MAXTYPES] = { [0 ... 12] = 0 }, *types ;
        types = count_types( sorted, type ) ;
        for ( int f = 0 ; f < MAXTYPES ; ++f )
        {
            if ( types[f] == 2 ) { return 2; } /* found normal pair */
        }
    }
    return 1 ; /* player only has a high card value */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A key problem is that this code only returns the kind of poker hand.  Given that subsequent code will need to *compare* hands, like which *straight* is better, it makes sense that this code not only rate the kind of hand, but also provide info like top card in a straight, or rank of the cards that make up 2-pairs.
2. Inconsistent use of magic numbers and macros.  Why `MAXTYPES` and then `12`.

   ```
   //int type[MAXTYPES] = { [0 ... 12] = 0 }, *types ;
   int type[MAXTYPES] = { 0 };
   ```
3. Recommend to avoid declaring variables of different types on the same line.  Instead consider initializing as part of the declaration

   ```
   // int type[MAXTYPES] = { [0 ... 12] = 0 }, *types ;
   // types = count_types( sorted, type );
   int type[MAXTYPES] = { [0 ... 12] = 0 };
   int *types = count_types( sorted, type );
   ```
4. Odd to use a `enum` for the suits and then magic numbers for return codes

   ```
       switch (hand[i].nSuit) {
           case spades:    suits[0]++; break;
           ...
           else return 9;
   ```
5. Flush code can be simplified.  Only need to check if the cards all have the same suit as the first.  Similar code can be used to determine a straight with sorted cards

   ```
   bool flushsuit = true;
   for (int i = 1; i < MAXHAND; ++i) {
     if (hand[0].nSuit != hand[i].nSuit) {
       flushsuit = false;
       break;
     }
   }
   ```
6. The redundant code for check of pairs, 3-of-a-kind, etc. can also be simplified.  Given their similarities, consider combining code

   ```
   #define RANK 13

   group[MAXHAND+1] = { 0 };
   rankcount[RANK] = { 0 };
   for (int i = 0; i < MAXHAND; ++i) {
     int rank = hand[i].nType;
     rankcount[rank]++;
     group[rankcount[rank]]++;
   }

   if (group[5]) return five_of_a_kind;
   if (group[4]) return four_of_a_kind;
   if (group[3] && group[2] > 1) return full_house;
   if (group[3]) return three_of_a_kind;
   if (group[2] > 1) return two_pair;
   if (group[2]) return pair
   ```
7. Functions that do not change pointed-to objects, use `const`

   ```
    // int checkhand (struct Card_s * hand);
    int checkhand (const struct Card_s * hand);
   ```
8. To determine if the hand is a straight, without sorting, consider a bit array:

   ```
   unsigned ranks = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < MAXHAND; ++i) {
     int rank = hand[i].nType;
     ranks |= 1u << rank;
   }

   // Replicate lo_ace as hi_ace 
   ranks |= (ranks & ACE) << RANK;

   #define FIVE_IN_A_ROW 0x1F
   bool IsStraight = false;
   while (ranks) {
     if (ranks & FIVE_IN_A_ROW == FIVE_IN_A_ROW) {
       IsStraight = true;
       break;
     }         
     ranks >>= 1;
   }
   ```